# Navigation not highlighting properly with scrollspy

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, scrollspy

You can see my development here - http://anspro.webminister.in/
When I click the links in navigation bar, the page is getting scrolled to the right point - but the link is not getting highlighted, I had to set an offset

```
var offset = 111;   
$('.navbar li a').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $($(this).attr('href'))[0].scrollIntoView();
    scrollBy(0, -offset);
});
```

Now my issue is, when I am trying to scroll the page, the navigation is not getting highlighted properly. It is getting highlighted after I cross midway of the desired section. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I added the following code, and got it solved

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('body').data()['bs.scrollspy'].options.offset = 113;
});
```

the value 113 is achieved on trial and error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your fixed header.
It has a height of 111px thus your navigation is messed up.
Either go with the offset OR make the header NOT fixed, whatever you prefer :)